# How do I restore browser tabs which I have accidentally closed?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet-explorer

Sometimes in my haste to close tabs, I have accidentally closed tabs which I still want.

How do I restore a browser tab which I have accidentally closed?

Comment: Can you specify which of the browsers you are actually interested in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to restore the last closed tab. You may do this for several tabs closed, restoring them in reverse order they were closed. I don't know the limit, but it is greater than 15.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to restore the browser tab.